# Put option to view readme file at the end of InstallShield Setup

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am making an installer in InstallShield 8 and trying to put an option as in a check in the setupcomplete dialog, I am using the below link as help:

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106070

As also stated in this link:

> "An InstallScript custom action may not successfully launch from the
>   OK button control on the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog. This is because
>   the custom action ISCleanupSuccess is executed before the custom
>   action to view the ReadMe is launched. ISCleanupSuccess removes the
>   InstallScript engine from memory, and the InstallScript custom action
>   will not launch successfully."

when i run the ISComplete success event after running event that opens readme file i get this error:

"Errror 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the did not finish as expected. COntect your Support..." But read me file opens

They have written in the same link that InstallShield script may not launch from OK button in SetupCompleteSuccess dialog and yet they mention doing the same in the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok guys i found the solution here it is:

To launch a ReadMe file, follow these steps:

- Navigate to the Dialogs view and open the Dialog Layout for the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog.
- Set the TabStop of the Bitmap dialog control to True.
- Give the ReadMe check box control a value in the Value property if there is no value.
- Navigate to the Property Manager view.

-Add the property called SHOWLAUNCHREADME with a value of -1.

- Add the property called READMEFILETOLAUNCHATEND with a value of 1.
- Open the Custom Actions view.

-Add a Launch EXE custom action that launches a text viewer application and passes the ReadMe file to it.

- Navigate to the Dialogs view and select the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog.
  Insert this custom action as a new DoAction event on the Behavior of the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog for the OK button.
- As a condition on the new Doaction add the LAUNCHREADME property and set it equal to the value specified for the check box in step 3.
- (Optional) If you want the ReadMe check box selected by default, add the LAUNCHREADME property in the Property Manager. If you do not create this property, the dialog will display the check box, but will not have it selected by default.

**just make sure that for your launch exe event select Ignore custom action retun code in Return process, in custom action wizard.
and you place the event that opens ream me on top of ISCleanupSuccess in SetupCompleteSuccess OK button. and you should be fine.**

Comment: - Add a Launch EXE custom action that launches a text viewer application and passes the ReadMe file to it. -> Could use some more details.